# Dynamically include directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation where I would like to dynamically include directives/components to an angular template. The reason to why I want this is that I'm writing a dashboard which should be easy to extend with new widgets. I really like the directive/component thinking in angular and would prefer to be able to make a directive of each widget. I would then like to add each widget with an ng-repeat or something similar. This would make it very easy to add new widgets over time. My questions are first of all if this thinking is sound and secondly if anyone know if someone has written something like this that I can start with.

Example

```
vm.widgets = [{
    component: 'widgetA'
},{
    component: 'widgetB'
}]

<div ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets">
    <ng-include-component name="widget.component">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this worked for me:

Your view:

```
    <div ng-repeat="row in components">
        <div class="row">
            <div ng-repeat="col in row">
                <div class="col-md-{{col.width}}" ng-include="col.url"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Your controller:

```
        $scope.components = {
            'Row1': [
                [{
                    url: '/views/widget1.html',
                    width: '4'
                }, {
                    url: '/views/widget2.html',
                    width: '8'
                }]
            ],
            'Row2': [
                [{
                    url: '/views/widget3.html',
                    width: '4'
                }, {
                    url: '/views/widget4.html',
                    width: '4'
                }, {
                    url: 'views/widget5.html',
                    width: '4'
                }]
            ]     
        };
```

Comment: Yes, that would work but I would prefer if it was possible to use a directive name instead.

Comment: What would be this directive doing differently than ng-include?

Comment: I understand, you want to add a simple directive that creates all the dashboard for you... got it, I will edit my answer...

Comment: No, I don't want a directive that creates my whole dashboard. The functionallity of my proposed ng-include-component would be very much alike ng-include with the to difference that it takes a directive name instead of an url. I would like to be able to think about and refer to my widgets by their component name and not by the url.

Comment: @Abris Anyway in my humble opinion i feel that directives are not intended to do widgets. Templates should do the trick. In my opinion directives are intended to add behaviour to specifics component. Not being components itself. Maybe you could do this directive to include by its component name (but will finally only load the template associated to the component name)

Comment: When I read about angular 2 and the plan for angular 1.x I think that we are heading towards thinking more and more about components. For example, the new router which will be released in 1.5 is called component-router. If you read through this github issue, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10007, you will also see that there are plans on introducing a new way of creating directives that will be called something like component so that you can create directives with angular.module('dashboard').component('widgetA')

Answer (score 0):

I created my own directive that accomplish what I asked for in my use case  https://gist.github.com/Abrissirba/157e4c3bb87e724b35e1.

Answer (score -1):

use ng-if it creats elements on demand

```
<div ng-if="flag">
<div ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets">
    <custom-directive name="{{widget.component}}">
</div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
app.directive('customDirective',fucntion(){
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:false,
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
    scope.widgets = [{
        component: 'widgetA'
    },{
        component: 'widgetB'
    }];
  }
});
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you mean that I should add all my widget directives to my containg dashboard template? Wouldn't that mean that I can only have one instance of each widget? And it would also mean that I nead to change my dashboard template each time I add a new widget.

Comment: you can use contrller scope and do this with directives also

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. How would it be possible to add multiple instances of the same directive?

Comment: I still don't think you get what I mean. Your solution would force me to hard-code all the widgets that should be possible to see.

Comment: yes you right somehow you are not clear to me but you can change this variable from controller also..